# How to set a button if clicked, ignore the mouseout on vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a ToDoList and I'm using the 'mouseover'/'mouseout' duality to make an effect like hover. But, after a click, it was supposed to maintain the same layout as the 'mouseover' and ignore the 'mouseout', but the 'mouseout' effect prevails and the layout returns. How can I set the click to ignore the 'mouseout'?

```
  check.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event){
        check.style.cssText =  'cursor: pointer; color: #eaeaea; border: 1px solid #08a59d; margin-left: -40vw; padding: 4px; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #08a59d;'
    });
    check.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event){
        check.style.cssText = 'cursor: pointer; color: #08a59d; border: 1px solid #08a59d; margin-left: -40vw; padding: 4px; border-radius: 5px;'
    });
    check.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        task.style.cssText = 'width: 30vw; height: 30px; background-color:#5B8581; color: #eaeaea; text-align: center; margin-top: -4.3vh; border-radius: 10px; font-weight: 500; font-size: 18px; padding-top: 4px; text-decoration: line-through;';
        check.style.cssText =  'cursor: pointer; color: #eaeaea; border: 1px solid #08a59d; margin-left: -40vw; padding: 4px; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #08a59d;'
    });
        closebutton.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event){
        closebutton.style.cssText =  'width: 25px; cursor: pointer; color: #eaeaea; border: 1px solid #C70039; margin-left: 40vw; padding: 4px; padding-left: 6.2px; border-radius: 5px; margin-top: -3.7vh; background-color: #C70039;'
    });
    closebutton.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event){
        closebutton.style.cssText =  'width: 25px; cursor: pointer; color: #C70039; border: 1px solid #C70039; margin-left: 40vw; padding: 4px; padding-left: 6.2px; border-radius: 5px; margin-top: -3.7vh;'
    })
```

Comment: Why you don't use CSS   , element:hover property it would be much cleaner ( also mouse events aren't necessary here)!  Also after you click :active state is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with classes

```js
let task = document.querySelector('.task')
document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.target.classList.add('active')
  task.classList.add('active')
});
```

```css
.check {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #08a59d;
  border: 1px solid #08a59d;
  margin-left: -40vw;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.check:hover {
  color: #eaeaea;
  background-color: #08a59d;
}

.check.active {
  color: #eaeaea;
}

.task.active {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #5B8581;
  color: #eaeaea;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -4.3vh;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}



.closebutton {
  width: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #C70039;
  border: 1px solid #C70039;
  margin-left: 40vw;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-left: 6.2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: -3.7vh;
}

.closebutton:hover {
  background-color: #C70039;
}
```

```html
<div class='check'>Check div</div>
<ul class='task'><li>Task 1</li></ul>

<button class='closebutton'>X</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` method.
What this method basically does is stop all the other events' execution while an event happens so you could add it to your **onclick** event and it should solve the problem...
For more info [Check MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *truthy/falsey* variable to determine if the event is fired or not. `let disabled = false;` then in the event that `clicks` set `let disabled = true;` , then in the event for `mouseout` conditional that checks the value of `disabled` --> `if(disabled !== true){  // default behavior } else { // disabled is true stop default behavior }`

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
const show = document.getElementById('showme')

btn.forEach(button => {
  let disabled = false;
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log('clicked')
    disabled = true;
  })
  button.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    document.getElementById('showme').style.display = 'block'
    e.target.textContent = 'Mouse out to hide'
  })
  button.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
    if(disabled !== true){          
      document.getElementById('showme').style.display = 'none';
      e.target.textContent = "Hover to show"
    }else{
      show.textContent = 'Now mouse out is disabled...'
    }
    
  })
})
```

```css
#showme {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Hover to show</button>
<div id="showme">I am shown, now click to set disabled variable to true</div>
```